# OAuth2 & Microservices : create an user

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, oauth-2.0

I'm using a React Application and a separate Express API.

I need to register an user with my react app, If I understand correctly oauth2 flows, it should :

- Ask for user information (username, password, ..)
- Connect the API with client_credential grant type to retrieve an access token
- Use this access token to create the user at a specific endpoint

My question is about security :

- How can I hide the client_secret & client_id of the react app source code ?

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is - You cannot hide it if you have to provide it with your app.